# How to sync state of two lists in a somewhat-slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created a horizontal journey, which is guided by icons. Later each icon will contain some information.

By clicking the arrows the visitor can guide itself through the journey:

[image: slider image]

How can I sync the icons inside the image and the buttons beneath, while making the buttons beneath also clickable?

Currently I trigger the arrows using `.next()` and `.prev()` to navigate:

```
var nextIcon = function() {
  var windowWidth = $('#image-holder').width();
  var current = $('#image').find('.current');
  var next = current.next();
  current.removeClass('current');
  next.addClass('current');
  var offsetLeft = - (next.position().left) + (windowWidth / 2);
  $('#image').css({"margin-left": offsetLeft});
}
```

which does not work for the buttons below, I could for example jump from the first to the fourth icon on click.

**[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbLrQa?editors=1010)**

I have seen a lot of "indexes" using `i++` inside sliders, but do not know how to adopt or create this. Is this a good idea for my case?

Comment: have you tried using modulus to loop the number back ? i.e. `i= (i+1)%numberOfSlides` . as for the syncing part just manipulate the same iterator `i`

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it using a slider similar approach by indexing my elements. Using jQuery `.eq()` it was quite easy to navigate through my elements.

[**Working demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbLQYJ?editors=1010)

I got the idea using [Sitepoints "Making a simple image slider with jQuery"](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/making-simple-image-slider-html-css-jquery/)